# Get total number of files and Sub folders in a folder

Tags: powershell, vbscript, directory, explorer, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a task to carry out 3 times a day on a WS2012R2 to get the Disk size, total number of files and folders including subdirectories from a folder on a remote server.

Currently I get this information by RDP'ing to the target, navigating to the folder and right clicking the folder to copy the info:

[image]

I have already tried the PowerShell script :

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Data -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

and other PowerShell scripts.

Which produced countless errors pertaining to not having permissions for some sub directories or simply gave results I didn't want such.

I have tried VBscript but VBscript simply cannot get this information.

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the count property:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem E:\Data -Recurse -File
($items | Where { -not $_.PSIsContainer}).Count #files
($items | Where $_.PSIsContainer).Count #folders
```

Comment: that Gives the error: Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 
260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-ChildItem E:\\Folder\ -Recurse -File).Count
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (E:\Folder\ String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: @MartinBrandl, Consider using a counter variable because any large file structure will fill memory. Of course doing this for any large file structure is horrifying...

Comment: Thing i'm confused about is you can see this info in the general tab when right click the folder so why are there issues in Powershell? do i need to use another Language?

Comment: Yes i have over 250,000 files and folders to sift through so no small task.

Comment: There's the path length problem which is a .NET thing and won't be fixed until everyone (and PowerShell) is using .NET 4.6.2. Then there's that you're acting as you counting it, not the operating system counting. It's very messy.

Answer (score 0):

**To summarise the comments so far.**

You can get the size of the C drive with:

```
    $Drive = "C"
    Get-PSDrive -Name $Drive | Select-Object @{N="Used Space on $Drive Drive (GB)"; E={[Math]::Round($_.Used/1GB)}}
```

But you cannot use something like the code below to count the files & folders for the whole C drive, but it works for simple filestructures and simple drives.
I use the code to calculate my other drives and for my homepath, just change $Path to e.g "$Env:Homepath".

> There's the path length problem which is a .NET thing and won't be
>   fixed until everyone (and PowerShell) is using .NET 4.6.2. Then
>   there's that you're acting as you counting it, not the operating
>   system counting.

```
[Int]$NumFolders = 0
[Int]$NumFiles = 0
$Path = "C:\"
$Objects  = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse

$Size = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum
$NumFiles = ($Objects | Where { -not $_.PSIsContainer}).Count
$NumFolders = ($Objects | Where {$_.PSIsContainer}).Count

$Summary = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{"Path" = $Path ; "Files" = $NumFiles ; "Folders" = $NumFolders ; "Size in MB" = ([Math]::Round($Size.sum /1MB))}
$Summary | Format-list
```

To run this on remote computers, I would recommend using New-PsSession to the computer/computers, then Invoke-Command to run the code using the new sessions.